# Sqlite PCL and Linq - Is SQLite.Net Table method loading the entire table into a collection?

Tags: c#, linq, sqlite, windows-phone-8

I'm a building a windows phone 8 application. I've decided to use Sqlite PCL in a portable library to cache some data.

I didn't find recent information on the internet whether I can use or not linq on a table.

Of course I can do that

```
var phones = db.Table<PhoneNumber>().Where(x => some condition).ToList();
```

If I take a look at the return value of the `Where` statement, it is a `TableQuery`.

My question is : Do I retrieve all the phone numbers by doing this and then use Linq to filter the items?
Or does linq filter the items directly in the sql command before returning them?

To my mind, I wound say that Linq filters the items directly in the sql statement as the `Where` function return a `TableQuery` but I didn't find any confirmation yet.

2nd question: Is it the same when I use `FirstOrDefault`?

Comment: `linq` is a querying language, and not an implementation of a language. You need to convert your `linq` query to `SQL`, and the bare minimum for that is an `ORM` with a `LinqProvider`. You should look at `LinqToSQL` `EntityFramework` and `nHibernate`, as the most popular Linq implementations against SQL databases. However you should almost certainly avoid L2S.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Apparently, it's not that obvious. I've just found a very interesting forum post [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/11883/is-sqlite-net-table-method-loading-the-entire-table-into-a-collection)

To summarize, if you do this

```
var whereFirstOrDefault = Table<AlertType>().Where(a => a.Name.Equals(alertType.Name)).FirstOrDefault();
```

It is very different than doing this

```
var firstOrDefault = table.FirstOrDefault(a=> a.Name.Equals(alertType.Name));
```

The first query generates this command and does not retrieve the whole table:

```
select * from "AlertType" where ("Name" = (?)) limit 1
```

However, the second query is :

```
select * from "AlertType"
```

As mentionned,

> "SQLite.TableQuery has an extension method for 'Where' which takes a
>   predicate."

That means that Linq will modify the sql statement in consequence.

> "But SQLite.TableQuery only has a FirstOrDefault that doesn't take
>   parameters:"

It means that, if you use `FirstOrDefault` with a predicate, it will retrieve the whole table but if you use it without a predicate on a tablequery, it will modify the sql statement

> "If you call FirstOrDefault with a predicate (my second approach),
>   SQLite.NET selects the entire table and then uses LINQ To Objects to
>   do the FirstOrDefault on the collection in memory."